# afterPropertiesSet() method in spring life cycle

Tags: spring

What is the use of afterPropertiesSet() life cycle method of spring bean? For what kind of activities it can be used in real world applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the method name [afterPropertiesSet()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html#afterPropertiesSet--) hints, it will be invoked by the `BeanFactory` after all the properties have been provided, and can be used to initialize a bean or making sure is in a valid state.

Let's say I have a bean with a String property that must not be null or empty.

```
public class MyBean implements InitializingBean {

private String myString;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        if(myString == null || myString.isEmpty()){
            throw IllegalStateException("myString must have text.");
        }
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString) {       
        this.myString = myString;
    }
}
```

Of course this is only a very simple code to demonstrate how can be used in real applications.

HTH,

Jose Luis